# Checking pandas Timestamp for timezone string

Tags: python, pandas, timestamp, timezone

In the code below I want to acquire the timezone of a pandas Timestamp supplied to a function:

```
import pandas as pd
import pytz

timestamp = pd.Timestamp("2022-05-01", tz='Europe/Paris')
print(timestamp.tzinfo)
```

This prints:

```
Europe/Paris
```

However, I would like to check whether the timezone matches the timezone that I want and return a boolean value, such as:

```
timestamp.tzinfo == 'Europe/Paris'
```

But this returns `False`. Is there anyone here who knows a clever of checking the timezone of a timezone aware pandas Timestamp?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Checking the type

```
type(timestamp.tzinfo)

pytz.tzfile.Europe/Paris
```

We can see this is not a string, but some type of pytz object.

However if we look closer we can see there is a .zone which does return a string and is probably what you are looking for.

```
timestamp.tzinfo.zone == 'Europe/Paris'

True
```